# ASP.NET - Escolher vários registos a partir de uma dropdown

Tags: asp.net

Estou a desenvolver uma aplicação web em ASP.NET MVC onde pretendo ter uma página que permita ao utilizador seleccionar um ou mais exames para se inscrever a partir de uma dropdown e apresentar os exames escolhidos numa tabela. A qualquer altura, o utilizador poderá remover um exame escolhido da tabela se assim o desejar.

Para poder ilustrar melhor o que pretendo, podem visualizar a imagem em baixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tendo em conta que tenho muito pouca experiência em ASP.NET, gostaria de saber se existe algum exemplo semelhante ao que pretendo implementar para me poder basear.

Comment: Antes de mais nada leia esse post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485

Comment: Do jeito que a pergunta está soa como `Faça isso por mim` que não é o foco deste site

Comment: Use o controle `@Html.ListBoxFor` que vai fazer isso que você quer, mas não com esse estilo

Answer (score 0):

Acabei por encontrar um exemplo que ajudou bastante. Não é bem o que pretendo mas já é uma grande ajuda. Deixo-o aqui para quem precisar: https://weblogs.asp.net/brijmohan/twoselect-user-control-moving-items-between-listbox-controls-part-1